# Combining dictionaries: No class method for selector "addEntriesFromDictionary"

Tags: ios, dictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I am struggling with a dictionary in which I want to create a new dictionary from a series of keys (P, SP, and RP).

I have attempted to create a new NSMutableDictionary that combines individual Dictionaries that have have all the values for the P, SP, and RP keys respectively, but have gotten the error "No class method for selector "addEntriesFromDictionary" "

Here is my code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [NSMutableDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:self.allSPPositions];
```

and

```
@interface className ()
- (void)addEntriesFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)otherDictionary;

@end

@implementation className
- (void)viewDidLoad {
```

Any help or insight would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is telling you exactly what's wrong. You're trying to add items from a dictionary to the NSMutableDictionary **class**. You need to send the ad items from dictionary message to an **instance** of NSMutableDictionary.

This line:

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = 
  [NSMutableDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:self.allSPPositions];
```

Should read

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = 
  [someDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary: self.allSPPositions];
```

(Where `someDictionary` is the dictionary to which you want to add items.)

or even

```
NSUInteger count = [self.allSPPositions count];
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = 
  [NSMutableDictionary dictonaryWithCapacity: count]; 
[newDict addEntriesFromDictionary: self.allSPPositions];
```

(Since your code appears to be trying to create a new, mutable dictionary and add the contents of `self.allSPPositions`.)

If your goal is to get a mutable copy of self.allSPPositions, there is a cleaner way to do that:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutablePositions = [self.allSPPositions mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhh, here's an example that will compile and use the method in question, you should probably NOT call that method in your Interface since it's part of Apple's framework and is already predefined, unless you have a special reason for doing so:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[dict setValue:@"Seattle" forKey:@"name"];

[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] forKey:@"age"];
[dict setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"date"];

dict[@"city"]=@"Seattle";

[dict addEntriesFromDictionary:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"Washington",@"location", nil]];
```

This is merely meant to get you started, but it shows you how to do this so that it works for you in your circumstances